# Set val to td by JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

Try to set my td value from my JavaScript JSON. But it dun seems to work when I inspect the element. However the html works just not the value. Not sure what is the problem. Tried changing the id to class too but it didnt work as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".login_a").click(function(){
    var test = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var topost = 'getMilestoneDetail.php='+test;
    var returnResults = $.getJSON('getMilestoneDetail.php?id='+test,function(data)
    {
        $("#td_projectName").html(data.projectName);
        $("#budget_amt").html(data.budget);
        $("#milestone_1").html(data.mileStone1);
        $("#percentage_1").html(data.percentage1);
        $("#percentage_1").val(data.percentage1);


    });
});
</script>

<div id="login_form">
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th> Project Name </th>
<td id="td_projectName">
</td> 
</tr>

<tr>
<th> Budget</th>
<td id="budget_amt"> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Stages</th>
<th>Payment Percentage</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td id="milestone_1"> 
</td>
<td id="percentage_1">
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input, select and textarea`. Why do you want to set the value ?

Comment: i need to set the value for the `td` because I will need to get the value of it in the later part. Or maybe I can put a hidden type inside the td and store the val in it? Will it work the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.val(value)` method is primarily used to set the values of form elements such as `input, select and textarea`.

You can use a hidden field to keep the value or you can use `.text()` method to get the text of `td`.

```
<td id="percentage_1">
    <input type="hidden" id="percentage_1_val" />
</td>

$("#percentage_1_val").val(data.percentage1);
```

Get the value.

```
$("#percentage_1_val").val(); 
// or you can use $("#percentage_1").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

VAL is not a valid attribute of a TD, and that is why you cannot set it.  If you want to store some data as an attribute of the node, the use setAttribute to store it.  Example:

Straight JS:

```
document.getElementById('percentage_1').setAttribute('bob', 'your uncle');
```

Or using jQuery:

```
$('#percentage_1').attr('bob', 'your uncle');
```

You would use getAttribute, or .attr, to get the value later, e.g.

```
var bob = document.getElementById('percentage_1').getAttribute('bob');
```

or

```
$('#percentage_1').attr('bob');
```

**Note that non-standard attributes won't validate** and may be frowned on, but are common fixtures in web applications.  **You can use jQuery's .data method to properly set data on a node if you are unconcerned with older browser support.**